# User Summary not displaying users list

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I am very new this openfire . i am able to create the user from the admin console but it don't show the user names in list . but its show no of us as show bellow. give me the suggestion..
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There must be a mistake in your System Properties under Server Manager in Openfire.

Check this link: http://dev.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-flexible-xmpp-chat-for-a-member-based-website-with-flash-and-php--active-9858

It has a complete tutorial on how to install and configure Openfire

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. i got below answer. It works for me. It may help you.

It appears that you can update your mysql jdbc driver by replacing the one under the Openfire installation directory's lib/ directory. It's called "mysql.jar" right now... just back that up, download the latest from mysql's site, and copy it into that lib/ directory (making sure to call it the same name - mysql.jar).